# Hyper-V-VM loses host share on reboot

Tags: hyper-v, network-share

I am running a CentOS7-HyperV-VM on a Windows 10 Pro machine. On the windows host I have a folder, shared with username/password, to which the VM can connect and mount.
As soon as i reboot the host, the vm cannot connect to the folder any longer. After a long search i managed to get it working again, but only by manually removing the "file & printer sharing" on the virtual ethernet adapter, and then turn it back on again. After that it is working fine ... until the next reboot ...
Updates are up-to-date.

Anyone got any ideas on this topic?

Comment: Cant connect, by ip or hostname? as you use a win10 I guess its in a workgroup?

Comment: I'm always connecting via ip (not working if bug is in effect), and Windows host is in a domain.